How to update Node.js to the latest version in Ubuntu 22.04
I'm getting this error message when I run npm run dev on my Nextjs project .
$ npm run dev
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- /home/rashmika/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /home/rashmika/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rashmika/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/rashmika/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/home/rashmika/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}


This is what worked for me.

Check your current Node.js version.
node -v


Update nvm (Node Version Manager) to the latest version.
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash


Restart your terminal or run:
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion (optional)


Install the LTS version of Node.js.
nvm install --lts


Use the newly installed version.
nvm use --lts


Verify the new version.
node -v
npm -v



